# JavaFX exception loading FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I have been working on a desktop application, where I need to use JavaFX. I have created various FXML files in a JavaFX project on eclipse built with Scene Builder. I have no issues loading any FXML file except for this one pesky file (FXMLImgList.fxml).

The main idea is that when a button is pressed, a new window appears. Here is my code for the event handler for that button:

```
@FXML
private void handleOnActionButtonImg(ActionEvent e) throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException
{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/res/FXMLImgList.fxml").toURI().toURL());
    VBox root = null;
    try {
        root = (VBox) loader.load(); // ERROR LOADING HERE
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    ImgListController ilc = loader.getController();
    ilc.init(imgUrl);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stage.initOwner((Stage) vBox.getScene().getWindow());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setTitle("Elegir imagen");
    stage.show();
}
```

The project in the package explorer looks like so:

> https://image.ibb.co/ihGMoS/Capture.png (Can't post images)

I get this exception from the try-catch block:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/C:/Users/Ximo/Desktop/UNI/2017-2018%20(UPV)/IPC/EclipseWorkspaceIPC/PL03_Ej2/bin/res/FXMLImgList.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at application.VentanaController.handleOnActionButtonImg(VentanaController.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown protocol: c
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1121)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:659)
    at application.ImgListController.initialize(ImgListController.java:64)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1115)
    ... 64 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:336)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:194)
    at application.VentanaController.handleOnActionButtonImg(VentanaController.java:116)
    ... 58 more
```

What's even stranger, the rest of the FXML files load just fine, for example this one:

```
@FXML
private void handleOnActionButtonMod(ActionEvent event) 
{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/res/FXMLVentana.fxml"));
    VBox root = null;
    try {
        root = (VBox) loader.load(); // NO ERROR LOADING HERE
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    VentanaController vac = loader.getController();
    vac.init(observablePersonData, table.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().getValue());
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stage.initOwner(this.stage);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setTitle("Modificar");
    stage.show();
}
```

The idea behind this event handler is pretty much the same, *press button -> window opens* and works just fine. I've tried many this like editing the returned URL but nothing seems to work.

I've notice the message on line 67:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown
>   protocol: c

However the result of:

```
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/res/FXMLVentana.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/res/FXMLImgList.fxml"));
```

Outputs:

> file:/C:/Users/Ximo/Desktop/UNI/2017-2018%20(UPV)/IPC/EclipseWorkspaceIPC/PL03_Ej2/bin/res/FXMLVentana.fxml
>
> file:/C:/Users/Ximo/Desktop/UNI/2017-2018%20(UPV)/IPC/EclipseWorkspaceIPC/PL03_Ej2/bin/res/FXMLImgList.fxml

Here's the code for FXMLImgList.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" spacing="12.0" xmlns="        http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.151" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ImgListController">
   <children>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" spacing="12.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="cancelar" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOnActionButtonCancelar" text="Cancelar" />
            <Button fx:id="salvar" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOnActionButtonSalvar" text="Salvar" />
         </children>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets />
         </VBox.margin>
      </HBox>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="12.0" left="12.0" right="12.0" top="12.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

And here's FXMLVentana.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox fx:id="vBox" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" spacing="12.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.151" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.VentanaController">
   <children>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="30.0">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="53.0" text="DNI" />
            <TextField fx:id="dni" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="30.0">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="53.0" text="Nombre" />
            <TextField fx:id="nombre" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="30.0">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="Apellidos" />
            <TextField fx:id="apellidos" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="30.0">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="Ciudad" />
            <TextField fx:id="city" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="30.0">
         <children>
            <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="Provincia" />
            <TextField fx:id="province" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="12.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="imgView" fitHeight="80.0" fitWidth="80.0" onMouseClicked="#handleImgMouseClick" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio    ="true" />
        <Button     fx:id="buttonImg" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOnActionButtonImg" text="Imagen" />
     </children    >
  </HBox    >
  <    HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" spacing="12.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="buttonCancelar" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOnActionButtonCancelar" text="Cancelar" />
            <Button fx:id="buttonAction" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOnActionButtonAction" text="Salvar" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="12.0" left="30.0" right="30.0" top="12.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

In conclusion, I'm all out of ideas and nothing I find onlince seems to solve the issue. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Show your project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stacktrace there are 2 exceptions.

The one at the end simply indicates that `root` is null when you try to pass it to the constructor of `Scene`. This happens since loading the fxml failed. This is not because of an invalid fxml url, it's the result of creating a `Image` with a value that is not a URL as constructor parameter in the `ImgListController.initialize` method. Probably you pass an absolute file path.

You could use the `File` or `Path` classes to get a URL for a file:

```
File f = ...
URL url = f.toURI().toURL();
Image img = new Image(url.toExternalForm());
```

---

**Note:** You should not simply proceed with your logic if an exception happens and the rest of the method relies on the try-block from finishing without an exception. This way you get 2 exceptions, not just one.

Alternatives would be:

- Rethrowing

  throw new IllegalStateException("This should not happen", e1);
- Returning after showing an error to the user/logging the error.
- ect...

Comment: Completely missed that... Thanks!